# Sending Email in SSIS Package on Azure Server

Tags: c#, email, azure, ssis, smtp

I’m a developer in a company in Turkey. We use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2016, Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015. In additional, our database is on Azure.
Also there are some privacy policies which are not allow me to setup plug-in to app or setup new application without permission.

Here is my problem. I need to develop a package in SSIS which sends an email. Because of Azure, as I googled SMTP server is not working. After my search,  I ahve found a solution and it’s senGrid.
However I tried to use it in a SSIS package, I couldn’t success. (The resason is that I’m new on SSIS and Azure) My team lead is pushing me about my task which has to send an email in SSIS package.

I need help about this subject but community of Microsoft doesn’t have enough knowhow. (I coudn’t find any solution to my issue.)

Could you help me? I can accept any kind of advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Azure SQL Database (not the SQL Server in the Azure VM), SSIS is not supported. And there is **no plan** to include SSIS in SQL Azure. We can get more info from Azure [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/471091-include-ssis-in-sql-azure).

If we want to use this feature, we can create the Azure VM SQL server. We need to create a new Integration Services project and [send mail task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/send-mail-task) and deploy it to SQL server.

[image]

We also could use [Azure Webjob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs) to send the mail. Please refer to another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276104/webjob-not-loading-sendgridmail-assembly/40280380#40280380).